# Searching a table for like matches based on 2 different vars

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits 2 values to the post target:

```
$fname=$_POST["fname"];
$lname=$_POST["lname"];
```

On the target page, I need to search the specified table for matches that are like $fname OR $lname. I'm kind of struggling with the concat part of it.

```
#    $user_info="SELECT * from player_data WHERE firstname like %'$fname'% or lastname like %'$lname'%";
     $user_info="SELECT * from player_data where '$fname' like concat(firstname, '%') or '$lname' like concat(lastname, '%')";
     $user_data=mysqli_query($con, $user_info);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_data,MYSQLI_BOTH))
     {
         $getfname=$row['firstname'];
         $getlname=$row['lastname'];
         echo "$getfname $getlname<br>";
     }
```

that first line that's commented, was something I was trying, figured should try to use concat instead.

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: You swapped the column name with your value.

Comment: thanks. Once I get all the functionality I'm looking for, I'll dig in to that more.

Comment: Is your intent for the WHERE clause to match "Pat" to rows having "Patrick" or "Paticia" or "Happat"?

Comment: yes @SloanThrasher

"Pat" could return Patrick or Heppat for the first name
OR
"son" could return Johnson or Sonny,  from the last name

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out...  %$var% works fine, but if one of the 2 were blank it was returning everything in the table. I appreciate the feedback and will definitely look into preventing sql injection.

Comment: Thanks for letting the community know about your solution,